# Subquery in JQuery QueryBuilder

Tags: query-builder, redquerybuilder, jquery-query-builder

I am going to use the JQuery Query Builder plugin in my project. I want to know how query will generate for relational table.

For example, I have two tables user and user_emails. I want to filter those users which have an email address. To get this result, I have to use subquery on user_emails table. Has that been possible by using this plugin? In the demo, I have not found this case.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is vague.  Do you want to build conditions in the jQuery-QueryBuilder for "All users with emails"?  You also want the jQuery-QueryBuilder to look and return something like the following?

[image]

After you clarify the community can point you in the right direction.